# Why is the degree of a morphism $\deg(f) \leq \deg(D)$ when $\operatorname{div}(f) + D \geq 0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over a field $k$, and fix an effective divisor $D$ on it. Assume that we have a non-zero rational function $f$ whose divisor satisfies $\operatorname{div}(f) \geq -D$ i.e. $f$ belongs to the Riemann-Roch space $L(D)$.

Why is it true that the degree of the morphism $f$ is upper-bounded by the degree of $D$, i.e. $\deg(f) \leq \deg(D)$ ?

There is a rough explanation here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2351537, but I don't get it. In general $f^{-1}([0:1])$ and $f^{-1}([1:0])$ have cardinality smaller than $\deg(f)$ - equality holds for *almost* every $p \in \Bbb P^1_k$. So I am not sure how to conclude.

(As mentioned in a comment, we need $D$ effective, otherwise $D = -\rm div(f)$ is a counter-example).

Comment: If the divisor isn’t effective, it’s false. Just take $D=-\mathrm{div}(f)$.

Comment: @Mindlack : thanks, I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the notion of multiplicity that you are missing. The degree of $f$ is the number of points above $[1:0]$ counted with multiplicity (aka ramification). This is the contribution of negative terms in $\mathrm{div}(f)$. Said contribution is larger than $-D$, which is a negative divisor, so it has degree higher than $-D$. Setting signs right, it follows $\deg{f} \leq \deg{D}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for $deg(f) = \sum_{f(p) = [1:0]} e_p(f)$ (where $e_p$ is the ramification index)? Does this work also if $f$ is not separable (say in characteristic $\ell > 0$)?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you can check Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Chapter 7: see the definitions of multiplicity for Cartier divisors, and compare with the ramification of the map $k[x]_{(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ mapping $x$ to $f$ when $f(p)=0$. So I think it keeps working even in positive characteristic.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reference. I guess corollary 3.9 p. 276 is useful. See also Proposition 12.21 in Görtz–Wedhorn.

Comment: If we write $(f) = (f)_0 - (f)_{\infty}$ as a difference of two effective divisors with disjoint supports, then because $D$ is effective, the inequality $(f) \geq -D$ can be re-written as $- (f)_{\infty} \geq -D$. Thus $\deg(f) = \deg( (f)_{\infty}) \leq \deg(D)$. (We recall that $(f)_{\infty} = f^*([1:0])$ has degree $\deg(f) \cdot \deg([1:0]) = \deg(f)$).